# HSQLDB SET FILES CACHE ROWS/SIZE and SET FILES WRITE DELAY do not seem to work as expected

Tags: hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB embedded.
The OS is Windows 7.

Here are the `SET FILES` properties as they appear in the script file:

```
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 32
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG FALSE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
```

From which I understand that data should be written to disk every 500ms. On the other hand, it should be cached in memory until either 10MB or 50,000 rows are in cache.

When I view the directory of the database after about a minute and 6,000 records, I can see this:

```
d:\tmp\test\hsqldb\Run_0>dir
 Le volume dans le lecteur D s’appelle DATA
 Le numéro de série du volume est 3C08-FEE7

 Répertoire de d:\tmp\test\hsqldb\Run_0

06/04/2013  07:10    <REP>          .
06/04/2013  07:10    <REP>          ..
06/04/2013  07:10                32 data.data
06/04/2013  07:10                 0 data.lck
06/04/2013  07:10                 0 data.lobs
06/04/2013  07:10                 0 data.log
06/04/2013  07:10                89 data.properties
06/04/2013  07:10             1,757 data.script
06/04/2013  07:10    <REP>          data.tmp
               6 fichier(s)            1,878 octets
               3 Rép(s)  73,975,611,392 octets libres

d:\tmp\test\hsqldb\Run_0>
```

Please, notice the sizes.

So, I deduce that `SET FILES WRITE DELAY` is overridden by `SET FILES CACHE` properties.

Am I correct? What happens if the cache is overflown before 500 ms is over? Will it be flushed or will the 500ms delay be observed?

**EDIT**

This is strange. I distribute data amongst 50 distinct HSQLDB embedded databases (using 50 different data source objects).
Each DB has three CACHED tables:

```
CREATE TABLE RUNSTATS
(
   ID      BINARY(16)   NOT NULL,
   ENTITY  BLOB(128K)     NOT NULL
   ,CHECK (PUBLIC.RUNSTATS.ID IS NOT NULL)
   ,CHECK (PUBLIC.RUNSTATS.ENTITY IS NOT NULL)
);

ALTER TABLE RUNSTATS
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_runstats
   PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX
(
   ID          BINARY(16),
   TIMESTAMP   BIGINT,
   FLOWID      VARCHAR(200),
   AVGLATENCY  DOUBLE
);

ALTER TABLE RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_runstats__avglatencyindex
   PRIMARY KEY (ID, FLOWID);

CREATE INDEX IDX_RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX_FLOWID
   ON RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX (FLOWID ASC);

CREATE TABLE RUNSTATS__CLIENTGWTOTALININDEX
(
   ID          BINARY(16),
   TIMESTAMP   BIGINT,
   FLOWID      VARCHAR(200),
   CLIENTGWTOTALIN  DOUBLE
);

ALTER TABLE RUNSTATS__CLIENTGWTOTALININDEX
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_runstats__clientgwtotalinindex
   PRIMARY KEY (ID, FLOWID);

CREATE INDEX IDX_RUNSTATS__CLIENTGWTOTALININDEX_FLOWID
   ON RUNSTATS__CLIENTGWTOTALININDEX (FLOWID ASC);
```

Up to now **each** database has received 26,000 RUNSTATS objects (about 1K each), 52,000 RUNSTATS_*AVGLATENCYINDEX and 52,000 RUNSTATS*_CLIENTGWTOTALININDEX objects.

Here is the dir of an arbitrary DB instance out of 50:

```
d:\tmp\test\hsqldb\Run_12>dir
 Le volume dans le lecteur D s’appelle DATA
 Le numéro de série du volume est 3C08-FEE7

 Répertoire de d:\tmp\test\hsqldb\Run_12

06/04/2013  07:10    <REP>          .
06/04/2013  07:10    <REP>          ..
06/04/2013  08:25         8,388,608 data.data
06/04/2013  07:10                 0 data.lck
06/04/2013  07:10                 0 data.lobs
06/04/2013  07:10                 0 data.log
06/04/2013  07:10                89 data.properties
06/04/2013  07:10             1,757 data.script
06/04/2013  07:10    <REP>          data.tmp
               6 fichier(s)        8,390,454 octets
               3 Rép(s)  33,617,223,680 octets libres

d:\tmp\test\hsqldb\Run_12>
```

The RAM of the java process has grown to over 3GB.

The RUNSTATS objects should go to the lobs file, shouldn't they? So why is this file reported as empty? If a RUNSTATS object takes about 1K, then the 10,000K limit is reached after about 10,000 objects, but over 26,000 were already inserted!

Please, explain to me this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reading of the directory during operations may not show the real file sizes. These sizes show up correctly after a shutdown.

The RUNSTATS blobs go to the lobs file. The rows are in the data file. Each blob will take between 32K (SET LOB SCALE 32) and 128K in the lobs file.

The WRITE DELAY setting is related to the log file only. It does not aply to the cache and the data file.

In Windows, you can use the Explorer to view the file properties after right clicking on it. This should show the current file size during operations.

Comment: The BLOB granularity is determined by the `LOB SCALE` property?

Comment: Not after inserting lobs. 32 is OK if your lobs are average 32K or more.